# How To Get data by key (mobile number) in firebase web application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have record in User table in firebase and I want data by mobile number.
**mobile number is primary key in user table**.

I have code for getting data from table but in that code I am using loop so process taking time to get any one record from table. I have more then 3000 records in my users table. anyone have idea that how can I get a single record by key in Firebase table using javascript or jquery?

**[Here is my table Structure Image]**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
firebase.database().ref('users').child('1234567890').once('value').then( function(snap) {
    const user = snap.val()
    const userKey = snap.key
})
```

So using this, you can fetch the particular user you want. `snap.val()` will give you user object and `snap.key` will give the key (in this case key = 1234567890). This is the code for javascript.

Comment: var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
  ref('users').child('1234567890').once('value', function(snap) {
    const user = snap.val()
    const userKey = snap.key
})
Is it fine?

Comment: yes, both can be done. I have used admin privilege. (accessing firebase db being admin)

Comment: @BAndroidDeveloper once() returns a promise, so it should be like this: `once('value').then(function (snap) {`, also you need to use one `ref("users")` not two

Comment: Welcome. If it is working, then please mark this as correct answer. So that for someone else finding the solution may be helpful.